# what's the best practice to print out(print debugging information) for a class?

Tags: c++

I am wondering what's the best practice to print out a class (say classA), I have several method

classA ca;

1) Define a debug method and inside this method , print out all its members.

2) Define a str() method, and use cout<< ca.str()

3) Define something like string conversion(I am not sure how yet), and just use cout << ca

Comment: In your question, what is `ca`?

Comment: Your question should be more clear. And what is str()

Comment: It depends what is the class, and what data structures you have in mind. Are you concerned with cyclic graphs, or directed acyclic graphs, or trees? Do you have smart pointers? Which ones? Read more about [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization), [persistence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_%28computer_science%29)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way is to overload `operator<<` roughly like this:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, classA const &a) {
  // precise formatting depends on your use case. Do the same thing you would
  // if you wanted to print a to cout or a file, because that is what this code
  // will end up doing.
  out << a.some_data() << ", " << a.some_more_data();
  return out;
}
```

If `classA` has a limited interface (does not expose all relevant data members), it may be necessary to make the `operator<<` a `friend` of `classA`, such as

```
class A {
public:
  // stuff

  friend operator<<(std::ostream &out, classA const &a);
};

// private members can then be accessed
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, classA const &a) {
  out << a.some_private_member << ", " << a.some_other_private_member;
  return out;
}
```

There is not usually a good reason to prevent read access to private members that you then enable the user to dump out per `operator<<`, though, since it would be rather leaky access control.

This then enables you to write

```
classA a;
std::cout << a;

std::ofstream file("foo.txt");
file << a;

std::ostringstream fmt;
fmt << a;
std::string s = fmt.str();
```

and so forth.

As a style note: It is possible to write

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, classA const &a) {
  // precise formatting depends on your use case
  return out << a.some_data() << ", " << a.some_more_data();
}
```

This achieves the same thing as the split return because `operator<<` (by convention) returns the same stream object that was passed into it (to enable the chaining of `<<` as in `std::cout << i << j << k;`).

Style note 2: If there is nothing in `classA` that makes it difficult, an upgrade to this technique is to write

```
template<typename char_type>
std::basic_ostream<char_type> &operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char_type> &out, classA const &a) {
  // rest as before. Put it in a header because it is a function template now.
}
```

This enables you to write `classA` objects not only to `cout`, `cerr`, `clog`, `ofstream`, `ostringstream` etc., but also to their `wchar_t` counterparts `wcout`, `wcerr`, `wclog`, `wofstream`, and `wostringstream`. These are rarely used in practice, but often it will cost you nothing to implement this feature. The trick is that `std::ostream` and `std::wostream` -- base classes of all these output streams -- are aliases for `std::basic_ostream<char>` and `std::basic_ostream<wchar_t>`, respectively. That gives us this nice way to handle both (and potentially other) character classes without code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

clog can be an option if you want to log your steps of a process in some file and review the file later to see what goes wrong. Also you can check state of data members at certain interval by logging them externally in file.